# _OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe clang error is SWIFT

Tags: swift, stripe-payments

All, 
I have installed the Stripe SDK and I have added :

```
PassKit.framework
Security.framework
Foundation.framework
QuartzCore.framework
```

When I build the application (its empty) all it has got is my public key.

I get : 
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Stripe", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo6Stripe in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Have i got enough frameworks or am I missing any ?

Any help would be brilliant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're not properly `#import`ing Stripe.h. You'll need to create a bridging header for your project that contains `#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>`. For more, see Apple's guide to Swift/Objective-C interoperability: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/MixandMatch.html

Best,
Jack